# How to get Data Change Notification OPC UA Java Client

Tags: opc, opc-ua

I am using OPC UA java stack and developing an OPC UA client. I have made subscriptions and publish request to a monitored Item. I am using datachangefilter to set trigger if the value of the monitored item changes. Now I am able to get notification. But i want to get the notification only when data change occurs. I am using this code snippet

```
        DataChangeFilter datachange = new DataChangeFilter();
        datachange.setTrigger(DataChangeTrigger.StatusValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the correct DataChangeFilter. What's the problem?

Comment: I get notification even if the value doesnot change(publish response- notification message - notification data ). DataChangeTrigger.StatusValue report a notification if either the StatusCode or the value change.

Comment: Also i get notification only once after publish request. After that even if the value changes I am not getting any notification. Is there any easy way to create a listener for datachangenotification.